# Error when I run webshot in a loop, two examples. R, webshot, rvest. Too many variables?

Tags: r, rvest

I'm using the dev version of webshot. I have two snippets of code below. One works no problem, the other does not work.

Does webshot not work for larger loops?

Working Code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
library(plyr)
devtools::install_github("wch/webshot")



testloop <- c("aapl", "fit", "amzn", 
          "ASPN", "CCM", "CGG", 
          "CGI", "CHK" ,
           "CMU")
          #, "CSLT", "DHT")


for (i in testloop) {

  wurlShot <- paste("http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/",i, "/stock-chart", sep = '')


  savepngname <- paste('"', i, ".png")

  webshot(wurlShot, file = paste('testfolder/',i, '.png', sep =''),  
          selector = ".marginT5px img")

}
```

But when I erase the comment and add two more runs in the loop:

```
testloop <- c("aapl", "fit", "amzn", 
          "ASPN", "CCM", "CGG", 
          "CGI", "CHK" ,
           "CMU", "CSLT", "DHT", "msft")


for (i in testloop) {

  wurlShot <- paste("http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/",i, "/stock-chart", sep = '')


  savepngname <- paste('"', i, ".png")

  webshot(wurlShot, file = paste('testfolder/',i, '.png', sep =''),  
          selector = ".marginT5px img")

}
```

I get this error:

```
Error in webshot(wurlShot, file = paste("testfolder/", i, ".png", sep = ""),  : 
  webshot.js returned failure value: 1
In addition: Warning message:
running command '"C:\Users\John\AppData\Roaming/PhantomJS/phantomjs.exe" 
"C:/Users/John/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/webshot/webshot.js" "
[{\"url\":\"http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/CGI/stock-chart\",\"file\":\"testfolder/CGI.png\",\"vwidth\":992,\"vheight\":744,\"selector\":\".marginT5px img\",\"delay\":0.2,\"zoom\":1}]"' had status 1
```

The only different is more loops are completed in the second one. Is there a reason why it fails?

Comment: There does not seem to be anything wrong with the code as it ran fine for me.

Comment: @Zak humor me, can you run it two or three times in a row? I think the error comes after I run `webshot` for multiple calls.

Comment: I ran it four times in a row inside a `while` loop and didnt have any issues. Sorry this wasn't too helpful!

Comment: Hmm, alright. Thanks @roarkz. I'll try and run it on a different computer see if I get the same issue.